# Next js v14 not passing the cookies to separated Node js back-end

Tags: node.js, next.js, cookies, axios, jwt

I have a Next js v14 application. I'm using axios to make a post request to an authorized route from Next js server, but the request not containing the cookies even if use fetch API.

I tried to do the request from the client-side with axios, and it worked perfectlly